# Unable to tag customer/Partner portal users

Tags: tag

I am unable to tag customers and partner portal users, using the @ function. I am able to do this for internal users, but not for any other users

Comment: check this User and Group @Mentions—Visibility   https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_mention_visibility.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the case if your [Portal User Visibility setting](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_owd_external_user_settings.htm) is disabled.
You can enable this by navigating to Setup -> Security Controls -> Sharing Settings, under Organisation-Wide Defaults -> User Visibility Settings.

Does that solve your problem?